# How to remove " " before and after array

Tags: php

How can i remove  `" "` from array start and after array end. I need array only without the `"`

```
  public function showPatientModal(Request $request)
    {

        $patient_id = $request->input('id');

        $data['patient'] = Patient::with('cases')->where('id', $patient_id)->first();

        $files_before = $data['patient']->file_before;
        $files_after = $data['patient']->file_after;

        dd($files_before);

    }
```

return me the following but i am getting the array as a string

```
"["download (2).jpg","download (3).jpg","download.jpg"]"
```

Comment: Can you give us some more context of your code?

Comment: that is probably,  json string, try `json_decode("["download (2).jpg","download (3).jpg","download.jpg"]", true);`

Comment: @Zeljka i have modified my question

Comment: @fazy show as methods file_after and file_before

Comment: Do you end up with an array, or do you want to get rid of the quotation marks at the beginning and end of the string? Note that removing the quotationmarks will not automatically mean that you end up with an array (although that would be an easy step with explode)

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = '"["download (2).jpg","download (3).jpg","download.jpg"]"';
echo substr($string, 1, -1);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = '"["download (2).jpg","download (3).jpg","download.jpg"]"';
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=^)\s*"\s*(?=\[)/', '', preg_replace('/(?<=\])\s*"\s*(?=$)/', '', $string));
echo $string;
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Btw, if you want to pass that to javascript, you're better off using [json_encode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

Comment: not worked for me you added more quotation ' before "

Comment: I'm not sure how that happened, but I noticed I had forgotten to add the regex delimiters. I updated the code.

I just tested it, it worked for me.